# Single-line musical score with text to notate prosodic rhythm

Tags: symbols, music, musixtex, lilypond

How can I have a single line musical score only to notate the quantity of each note and pauses? I've looked into some packages, but most of them only type entire traditional 5 lines score; I also tried packages with symbols, so that I could use tabular environment to place text right bellow the note, but usually they do not align rightly.

I want more or less to reproduce what is in this image.

thank you!
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you share the code for your attempts to use symbol packages? Maybe we can suggest some ways to do the alignment easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a [`lilypond`](http://lilypond.org/) file like

```
 \new RhythmicStaff \with {\remove "Staff_symbol_engraver"} {
    \relative {
        \time 1/4 \hide Staff.TimeSignature
    \tuplet 3/2 {a8' 8 8} 8 8 \tuplet 3/2 {r8 8 8}  8 8 4 }
    \addlyrics {
    Eye less in Ga za at the mill with slaves}}
```

I could produce something similar to examples

[image: ![enter image description here]

It's suposed that with package [`lyluatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lyluatex) the lylipond code can be inserted into a `.tex` file and compiled with `LuaLaTeX`. But I couldn't make it work yet on my system.

Comment: If someone is having trouble with the package, check this out: https://www.reddit.com/r/lilypond/comments/ockpgw/lilypond_in_latex_file/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MWE for lyluatex:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[pass-fonts]{lyluatex}

\begin{document}
\begin{lilypond}
\new RhythmicStaff \with {\remove "Staff_symbol_engraver"} {
    \relative {
        \time 1/4 \hide Staff.TimeSignature
    \tuplet 3/2 {a'8 8 8} 8 8 \tuplet 3/2 {r8 8 8}  8 8 4 }
    \addlyrics {
    Eye less in Ga za at the mill with slaves}}
\end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676807/150166) for details about how to use it.